# C++ Vector of vectors is messing with me

Tags: c++

If I put this code in a .cpp file and run it, it runs just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> row;
typedef vector<row> myMatrix;

void main()
{
    //cout << endl << "test" << endl;
    myMatrix mat(2,2);

    mat[0][1] = 2;

    cout << endl << mat[0][1] << endl;
}
```

But, if I make a .h and a .cpp file with the .h file like this, it gives me boatloads of errors.

```
#ifndef _grid_
#define _grid_

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> row;
typedef vector<row> myMatrix;

class grid
{
    public:

        grid();

        ~grid();

        int getElement(unsigned int ri, unsigned int ci);

        bool setElement(unsigned int ri, unsigned int ci, unsigned int value);


    private:

        myMatrix sudoku_(9,9);
};

#endif
```

These are some of the errors I get:

```
warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: What type does `main()` return?  I'll give you a hint:  it's `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify `vector` as `std::vector`.

It works in the .cpp file because you use `using namespace std;` (do *not* use `using namespace` in a header file).

Furthermore, your declaration of the member variable is incorrect.  It should just be:

```
myMatrix sudoku_;
```

If you want to set its dimensions, you need to do so in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The errors were a combination of:

1. not using namespace std; I generally add that even to header files (thats how my prof. taught me, but I've heard its not good coz it 'pollutes the global namespace'), but I used std::vector in this.

2. specifying dimensions while declaring sudoku_, and not in constructor;

Once again, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

As well as qualifying the namespace, you do not supply the constructor arguments for sudoku_ in the header file. You need to define your own constructor for grid and construct sudoku_ in the initialiser list:

```
grid::grid() : sudoku_(9,9) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize your `sudoku_` member object in its declaration like that.  That initialization belongs in a constructor initializer block.